# How can I mutate and create a new variable using for loops

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the current code to create a new variable called `hhid` in each dataframe within the list `hh02`.

```
hh02 <- list(exp_02, m1_02, m2_02, m3_02, m6a2_02, m6b1_02, m6b2_02, m6b34_02)

for(i in 1:length(hh02)){
 hh02[[i]] = hh02[[i]] %>%
   mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
}
```

However, when I run this code, I cannot see the new `hhid` variable in the dataframes. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You should put together a reproducible example.  We don't know what is in the dataframes in `hh02`.  You don't need to include all the entries, one or two should be enough, as long as your example reproduces the problem that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(hh02, \(x) mutate(x, hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso))
```

Note that you will see that this returns a list of frames, with the new column added, but it won't change `hh02`, or the frames initially placed in `hh02`

If you want to change the initial frames, you could do something like this

```
hh02 <- c("exp_02","m1_02")
for( h in hh02) {
  assign(h, mutate(get(h), hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso))
}
```